# St dev in periods defined by another variable

Tags: r

Here's what my data looks like (the structure):

```
omxh    coalition.inpower
 .01    2.4         (period begins)
 .03    2.4  
-.01    2.4
-.02    3.5         (another period begins)
 .02    3.5
 .05    3.5
 .03    3.5
-.01    4.1         (again another period begins)
-.03    4.1
 ...    ...
```

The first variable (being stock index returns) varies all the time but the other one (being the coalition in power) only changes once in a while. This is what it looks like then:

```
plot(lm(omxh ~ coalition.inpower))
abline(...)
```

[image]

So you can see that the volatility is different depending on the "block" of observations. How could I get the standard deviation for the first variable based on the periods defined by the other variable? The periods are not equally long.

Thanks. Something else you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tapply` or `aggregate`, e.g.:

```
tapply(df$omxh, df$coalition.inpower, sd)
```

Comment: Thanks. That does the trick. When I plot it, it shows the index from 0 to 50 even though the index vector has the right values from df$coalition.inpower, any ideas why?

Comment: I do `vol <- tapply(data$omxh, data$coalition.inpower, sd)` and then just `plot(vol)`

Comment: Try something like `plot(unique(data$coalition.inpower), vol)`.

Comment: Still says lengths differ.

Comment: The problem is that `vol` has 49 rows while the `data$coalition.inpower` has 50 unique values, how's that possible then?

Comment: @Roope: That's wired. I don't know why this happened (without seeing your data).